# Rails - Determine what properties on an object are set by a setter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Given this class:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :association1
  belongs_to :association2, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I know that when I set association1, it sets association1_id to the ID of object 1

```
m = MyModel.new
m.association1 = object1
#<MyModel id: nil, association1_id: 1, association2_id: nil, association2_type: nil>
```

I know that when I set association2, it sets association2_id AND association2_type

```
m.association2 = object2
#<MyModel id: nil, association1_id: 1, association2_id: 2, association2_type: 'ClassType'>
```

My question is:

Is there a function that can easily tell me what information is being set on an object in hash form?

```
MyModel.magic_function(:association1, object1)
# returns {:association1_id => 1}
MyModel.magic_function(:association2, object2)
# returns {:association2_id => 2, :association2_type => 'ClassType'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the stop gap solution I have for now, just though I'd share:

```
def self.magic_method(association, object)
  instance = self.new
  instance.send(association, object)
  h = Hash.new
  instance.changes.each do |k,v|
    h[k] = v[1]
  end
  h
end
```

Is this built into rails somewhere?

Comment: This should probably have been an edit to your question, rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for [`changes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes):

```
person = Person.new
person.changes # => {}
person.name = 'bob'
person.changes # => { 'name' => [nil, 'bob'] }
```

Comment: Changes is close, but I don't want to change my original object.  I want to see what will be changed without actually changing my object.  Ideally, I shouldn't need an instance of my object at all.